# Google gmail api rate limite exceed error

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am using google gmail api for read otp, but whenever I try to run this function it somethimes gave `user rate limit exceed`, here what I should change to overcome this error. this error i am getting intermittently

```
def get_otp():
    logger.info("------ get_otp function started --------")

    print("get_otp function started")
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
...rest of the code to read otp
```

Answer (score 1):

> user rate limit exceed

is flood protection. the best thing to do is slow your application down you are sending to many requests at once.